# ZAP Proxy unable to launch browser invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: java, zap

- Using OWSAP ZAP 2.8.0
- On Ubuntu 19.04
- With openjdk version 11.0.3 installed

---

When clicking the "Launch Browser" button on ZAP to launch the HUD enabled browser for ZAP, no browser is launched and an error is printed in the terminal (full output below).

I have already tried Chromium and Firefox - both have the same issue.

Another issue I've been experiencing, although potentially unrelated, is that when trying to use ZAP in Firefox I am unable to visit HTTPS sites due to the certificate not working correctly (even though it's installed on Firefox).

I have also tried launching it with `sudo zaproxy` (as opposed to just `zaproxy`)

While writing this I restarted ZAP and now the "Enable HUD" checkbox is unchecked and disabled (greyed out); clicking "Launch Browser" does nothing and prints the same error.

```
1564053694462   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.RrRH7dDl2ZK7"
1564053694915   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1564053694915   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1564053694915   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1564053694915   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 4758
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
59660 [ZAP-BrowserLauncher] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.extension.quickstart.launch.ExtensionQuickStartLaunch  - invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'my-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-21-generic', java.version: '11.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'my-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-21-generic', java.version: '11.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriverImpl(ExtensionSelenium.java:777)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriver(ExtensionSelenium.java:700)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.internal.BuiltInSingleWebDriverProvider.getWebDriver(BuiltInSingleWebDriverProvider.java:62)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriverImpl(ExtensionSelenium.java:639)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriver(ExtensionSelenium.java:509)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getProxiedBrowser(ExtensionSelenium.java:602)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getProxiedBrowserByName(ExtensionSelenium.java:566)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getProxiedBrowserByName(ExtensionSelenium.java:552)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getProxiedBrowserByName(ExtensionSelenium.java:542)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.quickstart.launch.ExtensionQuickStartLaunch$2.run(ExtensionQuickStartLaunch.java:227)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

---

Was recommended to replace openjdk with oracle's java. After uninstalling openjkd and installing java 12.0.2 I am still experiencing the same issue.
Now, when running zap with `sudo`, I get the following error:

```
/snap/zaproxy/4/zap.sh: line 51: [: -ge: unary operator expected
/snap/zaproxy/4/zap.sh: line 54: [: -ge: unary operator expected
Exiting: ZAP requires a minimum of Java 8 to run, found
```

Running `java --version` displays `java 12.0.2 2019-07-16`

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems in the past using **openjdk** with ZAP that went away after switching to the regular propietary **Oracle JDK**.

Comment: I recall seeing errors when using zap regarding version 11 openjdk being too new, something related to "this feature only supported on version 8" .

Comment: After uninstalling openjdk and installing java 12.0.2, I am still experiencing the same issue

Comment: Try 1.8 JDK from: java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp – user10216038

Comment: Also, the "unary operator expected" error is common when Java is not automatically found. Running "java -version" from your **Home** **Directory** should show what java is linked by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Upgraded Oracle JDK to v15, uninstalled v14, accepted firewall rules for jdk 15, and voilà, it's working again!